# Does the iPad 2 perform better than iPad 1 with CSS3 animations?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, css, hardware-acceleration

After developing with HTML5 and CSS3 applications on the iPad 1, we have been disappointed with the performance of CSS3 animations/transitions/transforms (hardware accelerated). We're hoping that the iPad 2 will bring more power and perform better with this stuff. But is that really the case?

We don't have access to an iPad 2 and have heard rumours that the iPad 2 still has glitchy, slow, unreliable issues with how it handles CSS3 animations/transitions/transforms.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: iPad 2 is better - but mostly because it has triple the memory available for web apps. Post your code and I can test it on our iPad2.

Comment: Also are you using the 3d syntax for transforms everywhere? 2d syntax doesn't kick off hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also developing a web app targeted specifically at the iPad, and using HTML5/CSS3. I had the opposite experience - I'm surprised at how smooth animation is, even on the iPad 1. Michael Mullany is right - most 2d transforms don't get GPU acceleration - be sure you're using transform3d or tranformZ(0).

On the iPad 2, the animation is nearly flawless - as good as the better native apps.

Of course - it depends on what you're animating.

In my case, it's a "carousel", with over a dozen panels, each containing a handful of form elements. (However, the transforms are simple left/right animation).

If you haven't seen them already, here's two spectacular (IMO) talks on the subject:

Paul Irish: http://paulirish.com/2011/dom-html5-css3-performance

Alex Russel: http://dayofjs.com/videos/22158462/web-browsers_alex-russel

From what I've seen, CSS3 animations are VERY easy to do wrong (or poorly), and performance suffers. With some tweaking however, it seems pretty awesome.

Also - say what you will about the content and the unorthodox UI, but try http://stuffwhitepeoplelike.com/ on your iPad. Plenty of rich, smooth, and complex animations that run well on the iPad, and great on the iPad 2. (Of course, there's also some animations that are pretty janky on both, so it goes to show how important it is to use them judiciously...)

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

iOS 5 brings the Nitro Engine to home screen web apps too, read here http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/06/ios-5-brings-nitro-speed-to-home-screen-web-apps.ars

Answer (score 0):

Depends if your web app is added to the home screen. Acceleration is less importante to the home screen web app than on native safari mobile.

This is an article you can read : http://macapper.com/2011/03/21/web-apps-saved-to-home-screen-anchor-safari-performance/

Comment: But considering that the iPad 2 is a lot faster, I think some acceleration is a given (supported by the OS or not, more CPU + GPU + same calculations == better performance)